# jQuery Validation Engine (Adding language support)

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I just found that great [jQuery Validation Engine tool](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine).

I understand that i must edit the [languages file](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/tree/master/js/languages) so i can add the Greek language support to it. 
What i do not understand is how this engine will fetch the `jquery.validationEngine-gr.js` that i am willing to create for the Greek Language. Is it hard-coded somewhere or what?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://posabsolute.github.com/jQuery-Validation-Engine/#usage/references),

> First include jQuery on your page
>
> ```
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
> ```
>
> Include jquery.validationEngine and its locale
>
> ```
> <script src="js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
> <script src="js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
> ```
>
> Finally include the desired theme
>
> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>
> ```

You can change the inclusion of `jquery.validationEngine-en.js` to refer to your own translation.